# Looking for Cantor's correspondence

Tags: mathematicians, reference-request, cantor

I am trying to collect all available letters written or received by Cantor or written between his colleagues about Cantor. I have searched already the literature given below. But I would like to collect further ressources. Thank you.

E. Zermelo: "Georg Cantor, Gesammelte Abhandlungen mathematischen und philosophischen Inhalts", Springer, Berlin (1932).

E. Noether, J. Cavaillès: "Briefwechsel Cantor-Dedekind", Hermann, Paris (1937).

Jean van Heijenoort: "From Frege to Gödel - A Source Book in Mathematical Logic, 1879-1931", Harvard University Press, Cambridge (1967).

I. Grattan-Guinness: "The correspondence between Georg Cantor and Philip Jourdain", Jahresbericht der Deutschen Mathematiker-Vereinigung 73 (1971) 111-130.

I. Grattan-Guinness: "The rediscovery of the Cantor-Dedekind correspondence", Jahresbericht der Deutschen Mathematiker-Vereinigung 76 (1974) 104-139.

H. Meschkowski: "Georg Cantor: Leben, Werk und Wirkung", 2nd ed., Bibliographisches Institut, Mannheim (1983).

W. Scharlau: "Rudolf Lipschitz: Briefwechsel mit Cantor, Dedekind, Helmholtz, Kronecker, Weierstrass und anderen", Vieweg, Braunschweig (1986).

W. Purkert, H.J. Ilgauds: "Georg Cantor 1845-1918", Birkhäuser, Basel (1987).

J.W. Dauben: "Georg Cantor: His mathematics and philosophy of the infinite", Princeton University Press, Princeton (1990).

H. Meschkowski, W. Nilson: " Georg Cantor – Briefe", Springer, Berlin (1991).

R. Ziegler: "Georg Cantor und Rudolf Steiner", Beiträge zur Rudolf Steiner Gesamtausgabe, Dornach, Nr. 114/115 (1995).

C. Tapp: "Kardinalität und Kardinäle", Franz Steiner Verlag, Stuttgart (2005).

J. Ferreirós: "Paradise Recovered? Some Thoughts on Mengenlehre and Modernism (2008).

B. Russell: "Autobiography", Routledge, London (2009).

Comment: Good collection letters, hope to be more